# Hosting AspNetCore.SpaTemplates Project on an IIS Server

Tags: angular, iis, single-page-application, asp.net-core-2.0, spa-template

My company is using ASP.NET for a few tools, and I thought I'd give using .NET Core and Angular a shot. I built my project out, tested it, published it, and set it up in IIS.

[image: Publish]

[image: File]

[image: Dir]

Unfortunately, the error message isn't very descriptive. I was wondering if anyone else ran into an issue like this when using .NET Core and Angular 2 with IIS. I'm guessing I missed something in the setup?

[image: IIS]

[image: Error]

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

I updated my web.config based on @Eliseo's feedback:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore"/>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\BrightApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 805b51a9-21a4-4f6f-8eb6-74955992b4d6-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of troubleshooting and stack-overflowing, I was able to resolve this issue by following first time setup guides for IIS (just to double check everything), restarting IIS, and opening the port on the firewall.

In hindsight, this was a bad question because the answer could have been a great number of things.

Answer (score 0):

it's look like there are a problem with you web.config. My web.config in my PC is slightly different, I have to add remove name="aspNetCore"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
          <!--I add this line bellow --->
          <remove name="aspNetCore"/> 
          <!---     --->
          <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyAplication.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Check too that the name of your application have no spaces and try to write in console

```
dotnet MyAplication.dll
```

Sorry, I hope this help you, but I don't know more

Comment: I tried this out, but unfortunately am still getting the same result - Error 0x8007000d. "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error - The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid."

Comment: Have your folder read/write permisions? I can not think of anything else :(

Comment: Thanks for giving it a shot. I was able to get further. I reinstalled dotnet core and node, now I'm getting note related errors. Finding .NET Core integration with IIS is more difficult than I thought. I'm looking into UseIISIntegration - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module?tabs=aspnetcore2x